# sitecore experience editor ribbon button

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8, ribbon-button

I'm trying to add custom ribbon button to sitecore experience editor. I am following steps for simple button from

http://www.programmingbynumbers.com/2015/01/31/creating-a-new-experience-editor-button-in-sitecore-8/

and everything goes fine until I get to the .cs file. I cannot find the reference to PipelineProcessorRequest and I am getting error. Can anybody share full c# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have working code but you can find `PipelineProcessorRequest`  in `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak` assembly, namespace `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Requests`